# Can a chrome extension access and alter a static HTML asset?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, web-component, content-script

I want to build a Chrome extension that will be able to inject a script tag into a statically served HTML file (which is not the page itself ie. not index.html).

I am able to do this on the *main actual page* (ie. `index.html`) with a content script with this in my manifest:

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "js": ["script.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
...
```

...and `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '[SCRIPT_PATH]');` in `script.js`, but what would I like to do is to perform this on another HTML file served as an *asset*, which BTW is being imported from my main `index.html` as a Web Component.

So in other words, can a content script access (and modify/alter) static HTML files served as source files (except the main `index.html`)?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: So here's my structure:

index.html contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Yay!</title>
  <link rel="import" href="foo.html">
</head>
<body>
  Sexy body woop!
</body>
</html>
```

foo.html contents:

```
<script src="bar.js"></script>
<!-- here I want the Chrome extension's content script to inject another script -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the imported document with the `import` attribute of the `<link>` element.

```
var link = document.querySelector( 'link[href="foo.html"]' )
var importedDoc = link.import
```

Then you can manipulate the imported HTML document as you would do with the main one:

```
//get the bar.js script element
var script = importedDoc.querySelector( 'script[src="bar.js"]' )
//append your script after it
importedDoc.body.insertBefore( yourScript, script.nextSibling )
```